# Unable to install PHP 7.4 Zip extension in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php

I'm getting this error when running `sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip`:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> php7.4-zip : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.12) but 7.4.10-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

The [PHP manual page for installing the Zip extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) says this:

> As of PHP 7.4.0, in order to use these functions you must compile PHP with zip support by using the --with-zip configure option. Previously, zip support had to be enabled by using the --enable-zip configure option. As of PHP 7.4.0, the bundled libzip is removed.

What is the straightforward method for getting the Zip extension installed on my system?

UPDATE: Additional information:

- `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns no held packages.
- `sudo apt autoremove` removed some packages but did not change the message returned by `sudo apt install php7.4-zip`

Comment: I had the same with PHP 8.1. I removed it completely via `sudo apt remove "php8.1-*"` and then just reinstalled via `sudo apt install php`.

Answer (score 0):

This below steps worked good for me on my Ubunut 22 and php7.4.  Add PPA for PHP 7.4 Add the ondrej/php which has PHP 7.4 package and other required PHP extensions.

```
apt install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php  
apt update
```

Then you can install the extension

```
apt install php7.4-zip
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-json php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-zip php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-curl php7.4-xml php7.4-bcmath
```

Answer (score -3):

Try apt-search for repo is exists for php7.4-zip

```
 apt search php7.4-zip
```

If repos are exists

```
apt install php7.4-zip
```

Or you can use the wildcard

```
apt install php7.4*zip
```